# Howto read list of selected mails with the Office.js API

Tags: api, office365, office-js, selected

The user can select emails in Outlook online by placing checkmarks in front of them. Is there a way to get the list of selected emails by means of the Office.js API?

Alternatively: is it possible to extend the [move to] button with custom options?

Answer (score 0):

Currently these 2 features you mentioned are not part of the Office JS API. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your requests there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process